# How to pass a generic to a React component and use that generic within the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building an input component that takes a `displayName` that is a string and a `value` that should be a generic. It also takes a function as a prop that needs to fire and handle that generic value when the input is changed.

So, let's say `MyInterfaceXYZ` holds the `displayName` and `value` like so:

```
interface MyInterfaceXYZ<T> {
    displayName: string
    value: T
}
```

We then want this generic value to be used in our main props interface that wraps our first interface... Like the one below (but my syntax is wrong I think):

```
interface MyComponentProps<T> {
    myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric: (value: T) => void
    options: MyInterfaceXYZ<T>[]
}
```

We then want to pass use this as our props in our react component - where we will receive a generic from an onChange listener.

```
// The syntax on the line below is totally invalid
const InputSelect: React.FC<MyComponentProps<T>> = ({
    myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric,
    options,
}) => {

    // `<T extends MyInterfaceXYZ>` requires 1 argument 
    // that I don't know how to pass here
    function onChangeHandler<T extends MyInterfaceXYZ>(option: T) {
        myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric(option.value)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <myElement onChange={onChangeHandler}>
                Blah blah!
            </myElement>
        </>
    )
```

How can I modify the syntax so the above code is valid?

Comment: Should the onChangeHandler be `function onChangeHandler<MyInterfaceXYZ<T>>(option: MyInterfaceXYZ<T>)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to make the `onChangeHandler` generic.

```js
import React from 'react'

interface MyInterfaceXYZ<T> {
    displayName: string
    value: T
}

interface MyComponentProps<T> {
    myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric: (value: T) => void
    options: MyInterfaceXYZ<T>[]
}
// The syntax on the line below is totally invalid
function InputSelect<T>({
    myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric,
    options,
} : MyComponentProps<T>) {

    // `<T extends MyInterfaceXYZ>` requires 1 argument 
    // that I don't know how to pass here
    const onChangeHandler  = (option: MyInterfaceXYZ<T>) => {
        myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric(option.value)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div onChange={() => onChangeHandler(options[0])}>
                Blah blah!
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

<>
  <InputSelect myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric={(a:string) => {console.log(a);}} options={[{displayName: 'string', value:'1'}]}  />
  <InputSelect myFunctionThatTakesMyGeneric={(a:number) => {console.log(a);}} options={[{displayName: 'number', value:1}]}  />
</>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-K8PCFUWabWkuNiMJ+4cRuQKRVK5Uxofx6QAdHUHI1cW5cUQYHYoJQQ0n5MJxPXYnJhEorK73X6vS0pNV45J0l3PT6-QoA1A8+HlNMAAyzRouJstlctgBCGkycDOm4AhM2W8JFu3l6uj6e5KXy43LMJ-oCQQGMHFEqnBunkVm0TnKr3qih9GMUxPQHaQnSGCAAwLK4zH-RoAG4XGJMMCV7aYpCUVQNG0XRHHwIDzHwLE4GLAx8FlfAXFmYk4EWU870oAFgVBZ8Uzhd9sgzFFswxX8+wAygVQuKBQKkcDlEgpBoIgWCUAQpC8WnNCMJUdRNB0PRDHwQSQGEoiSNsBx9FlKiaLo0hzyAA)

Also I changed the `onChange` to `onChange={() => onChangeHandler(options[0])}`, because you need to pass an option to the function. `options[0]` is probably not what you want.